# Why do people downvote questions that they cannot answer?

Tags: discussion

I find a lot of times I would ask and question and would get down voted a short while later while receiving no answers, some of the questions are easily answerable if you had the prerequisite knowledge.

For example, another day I asked for the general form of a random variable Z given that Z = X/Y

This is trivially solvable. Probability 101 stuff. I'm asking because I have forgotten it, but I know for a fact that everyone who have taken probability knows that it would involve some sort of convolution, some sort of jacobian matrix...you know...transformation of two RVs into another RV

Apparently, it got no answers and I chose to delete it a few days later. Oh, and I've searched everywhere for a solution to this problem, and there has not turned out to be anything useful

Do you also experience this? What should I do in cases like this?

Comment: The premise is that there are people who downvote and cannot answer.  What is the evidence of this?

Comment: People will ask me to provide further information to the question (in some cases they are making me literally to change the question). For example, I say that random variables X Y are independent, I would get follow up asking if they are also identically distributed - this changes the assumption of the question completely which simplies the question quite a bit and I get a downvote shortly after

Comment: I do not understand how asking such questions would change the question.  If someone asks "are they identically distributed", and the answer is "no", then you can reply "no". I don't know about this case, but in general asking such questions might help to clarify what you are asking, at least for some readers.  I don't see how this relates to the premise that people who cannot answer are downvoting.

Comment: Well I'm actually dealing with a case right now on math stackexchange (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960204/what-is-a-short-hand-for-random-variable-x-y-independent) with a person who called me obtuse and is downvoting my comments and accusing me of changing my question for not being able to answer my question. I am not going to accept a wrong answer even if you call me obtuse

Comment: ProjectBacklog: It is impossible to downvote comments, and there are no downvotes on the question you linked to.  It doesn't appear to be a good example for your claims.

Comment: flagging, sorry and it was downvoted from an upvote

Comment: ProjectBacklog: Users with over 1000 points can see the upvotes and downvotes on posts.  There are currently no votes.  Someone may have upvoted and then removed their upvote, but that is different from downvoting; it leaves it in the neutral position.

Comment: ...everybody can see all votes, when you ask the timeline: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/16985/timeline

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are assuming that people are downvoting because they don't know the answer. This is at best a specious assumption. It might be beneficial to pay attention to the tool-tips for upvoting and downvoting questions:

**Upvoting**

[image: This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear]

**Downvoting**

[image: This question dows not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful]

Nowhere in either tool-tip does it mention how easy the question is to answer. I don't mean to suggest that all up- and down-votes are cast following these guidelines, but a not-insignificant number of users will downvote questions lacking any demonstration of research effort, regardless of how "easy" (or "hard") they are.

---

Let us take note of the [question you mention in the OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/958085/8348). The link is 10K only, but it is pretty easy to reproduce in its entirety here:

> ### How do you find the probability density function of Z = X/Y?
>
> Can someone show me how this is done? Thanks

With absolutely zero research effort demonstrated this question would easily earn a downvote from me.

What you can do about this? Follow the guidelines laid out [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Would you downvote if you knew the answer? That is my question. I don't care how poorly the question was stated. If a first year calculus student ask me how to derive tan(x), I'm not going to say DO YOUR RESEARCH, I'm going to show him a proof that is intuitive and perhaps from an unconventional point of view. If you knew the answer to my question, would you still have down voted it?

Comment: Yes I would. And I have downvoted questions I know the answers to. Numerous times. And at the same time refrained from answering such questions.

Comment: Ok, why do you do this. This will answer the title of this post.

Comment: @ProjectBacklog: On some occasions, I might downvote questions that I answer. Sometimes before and sometimes after answering.

Comment: @ProjectBacklog: It won't answer the question in the title of your post. But the short answer is that math.SE's previous philosophy as a _laissez faire_ SE site with only the barest minimum of quality controls is simply untenable today as we get about 600 new questions every day (which will probably grow to at least 700 by December), and every question, good and bad, gets drowned out in the noise. Downvoting is one way to separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: "I don't care how poorly the question was stated." Well, I *do*, and so do a lot of people who have been here a lot longer than you have, and we don't want a lot of poorly-stated questions on this site, and we are happy to vote them to oblivion, whether we can answer them or not. It has been suggested that you invest a little time learning how to ask questions here; your interactions with the rest of us will go much better if you do.

Comment: Yet another reason I might downvote a question I can answer: I generally try *not* to answer simple questions immediately, so that users with lower reputation scores can answer them instead. But I don't mind voting immediately. I just wait a while before writing any answer.